# Async [TCP] writer close to avoid resource leaks

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm implementing a TCP client with asyncio [Streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams). Typical example code is:

```
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)
...
writer.close()
await writer.wait_closed()
```

The `...` is a non-trivial piece of async/await code in my case. To prevent resource leaks (e.g. fds), I believe I need to call that `close()` function, so I really should put it inside a try/finally. Is this correct or Python somehow magically handles resource cleanup, like it *finalizes asynchronous generators*, when async loop ends?

If not and manual cleanup is required, is there a more canonical/Pythonic way to implement this than defining a new function with [@contextlib.asynccontextmanager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.asynccontextmanager)?

I tried `contextlib.closing()` and `contextlib.aclosing()` but that doesn't work, since `asyncio.open_connection()` returns tuple and writer doesn't have `aclose()`, just `close()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always have to close streams when done.

You can use `try/finally`

```py
async def main_try_catch():
    writer: Optional[StreamWriter] = None
    try:
        print("Opening")
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("www.google.com", 443, ssl=True)
        print("Opened")
        data = await reader.readline()
        print(f"Received: {data.decode()!r}")
    except:
        print("Caught exception")
    finally:
        if writer is not None:
            print("Closing")
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            print("Closed")
```

Or you can use `@contextlib.asynccontextmanager`:

```py
@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def main_context_manager() -> Tuple[StreamReader, StreamWriter]:
    #  __aenter__
    print("Opening")
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("www.google.com", 443, ssl=True)

    yield reader, writer

    #  __aexit__
    if writer is not None:
        print("Closing")
        writer.close()
        await writer.wait_closed()
        print("Closed")
```

And use it like:

```py
import asyncio
import contextlib
from asyncio import StreamReader, StreamWriter
from typing import Optional, Tuple

async def main():
    # await main_try_catch()

    # OR
    try:
        async with main_context_manager() as (reader, writer):
            print("Opened")
            data = await reader.readline()
            print(f"Received: {data.decode()!r}")
    except:
        print("Caught exception")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())


# SUCCESS CASE
# Opening
# Opened
# Received: '...'
# Closing
# Closed

# ERROR CASE
# Opening
# Caught exception
```

Comment: The asynccontextmanager does not enter `# __aexit__` section if `open_connection()` throws. It's missing try/finally, so I believe you actually need a combination of both approaches. Will you edit your answer?

Comment: That is right .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the [helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76711475/2447844), I went with the following implementation in the end, which someone else might find useful (generic args and try/finally in context manager to ensure cleanup):

```
import asyncio
import contextlib
from typing import Tuple

@contextlib.asynccontextmanager
async def open_connection(*args, **kwargs) -> Tuple[asyncio.StreamReader, asyncio.StreamWriter]:
    writer = None
    try:
        reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(*args, **kwargs)
        yield reader, writer
    finally:
        if writer is not None:
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
```

Used as:

```
async with open_connection("www.google.com", 443, ssl=True) as (reader, writer):
    ...
```